# Trouble using new Api Config Params for Open Api codegen Typescript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, openapi-generator

I have a react client that is instantiating new Configuration class and passing that configuration in the endpoints generated by codegen open api

```
    import {
  Configuration,
  AuthApi,
  MemeApi,
  ConfigurationParameters,
} from "../generated-sources/openapi";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { UserApi } from "../generated-sources/openapi/apis/UserApi";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const bearerToken = Cookies.get("bearer");

const apiConfigParams: ConfigurationParameters = {
  credentials: "include",
  basePath: "",
};

if (bearerToken) {
  apiConfigParams.headers = { Authorization: "bearer " + bearerToken };
}
console.log("bearerAPI", bearerToken);
// Point to API
const configuration = new Configuration(apiConfigParams);

export const authApi = new AuthApi(configuration);

export const memeApi = new MemeApi(configuration);

export const userApi = new UserApi(configuration);
```

The problem I'm having is that after user logins in the authApi hook, I set the bearer token to the cookie however when I make a request to a route/endpoint that requires a bearer token, the configuration is not being updated with the new bearer token that I set to the cookie.

How can I make sure that this file, or this configuration listens to changes in the cookie and reinstate the calls?